# What does Limit Break actually do?

Tags: anime-gacha

On **Anime Gacha**, each unit has a level and a limit break - which is equal to the amount of them you have received from opening gachas.

What does this affect, or is it going to be used for the yet unreleased awakening feature?

**EDIT:** I found that having a full limit break will double the unit's stats, so the question would actually be - does this affect the characters before reaching full limit break (but to a lesser extent) or only once the maximum is reached?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, limit break is adding an additional percent to a unit's stats up to 100%.  You can see the limit break percentage by going to a unit's info page under their level.  So to sum it up, whenever you get more dupes, the limit break percentage increases, which in turn increases your unit's stats even if it is under 100%.  I have no idea if it is going to be for awakening.

You tagged it under Gacha World, but in your post you referred to Anime Gacha.  They are 2 different games.  Just thought I'd clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Limit break increases when you get duplicates of the unit by gacha-ing, but the 1st unit in the game (Gacha-Robo) has the most LB (at least, for me).

[image: Limit Break Bonus]

It gives you double the stats of the unit at 100%+.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! I've fixed up the image in your answer. I appreciate you taking the time to answer!